# appium automation using java

Tags: java, android, eclipse, selenium

I tried automating an android native app using selenium webdriver. See my code below.

```
package appium.eclipse;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;

public class NewTest {
    AppiumDriver<WebElement> dr;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setup() throws IOException{
        DesiredCapabilities first = new DesiredCapabilities();
        first.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "donatello");
        first.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY,"com.myapplication.MainActivity");
        first.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE,"com.myapplicationdev");
        dr=new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),first);
    }

    @Test
    public void launchapp() throws Throwable {
        Thread.sleep(9000);
        //insert pin
        for (int i =0; i<5; i ++) {
            dr.findElementByXPath("//android.view.View[@content-desc='1']").click();
            System.out.println("I clicked" + i );
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        //click login
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        dr.findElementByXPath("//android.view.View[@index='2']").click();
        System.out.println("I clicked Login");
        Thread.sleep(9000);
    }
}
```

However, Appium clicks the pin five times but does not click on the login button outside the loop. Appium returns success to the java client (eclipse) I'm using for the test.

Please is there something I'm doing wrong. I will greatly appreciate any assistance rendered.

@Manidroid, please see appium log below

```
> Launching Appium server with command: C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node.exe lib\server\main.js --address 127.0.0.1 --port 4723 --platform-name Android --platform-version 19 --automation-name Appium --device-name "donatello" --log-no-color
> warn: Appium support for versions of node < 0.12 has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please upgrade!
> info: Welcome to Appium v1.4.13 (REV c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a)
> info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:4723
> info: [debug] Non-default server args: {"address":"127.0.0.1","logNoColors":true,"deviceName":"donatello","platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"19","automationName":"Appium"}
> info: Console LogLevel: debug
> info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"appActivity":"com.myapplicationdev.MainActivity","appPackage":"com.myapplication","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"donatello"}}
> info: Client User-Agent string: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.1 (Java/1.8.0_101)
> info: [debug] Didn't get app but did get Android package, will attempt to launch it on the device
> info: [debug] Creating new appium session 60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6
> info: Starting android appium
> info: [debug] Getting Java version
> info: Java version is: 1.8.0_101
> info: [debug] Checking whether adb is present
> info: [debug] Using adb from C:\Users\Eagle\Desktop\Appium\Installations and Configuration\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe
> warn: No app capability, can't parse package/activity
> info: [debug] Using fast reset? true
> info: [debug] Preparing device for session
> info: [debug] Not checking whether app is present since we are assuming it's already on the device
> info: Retrieving device
> info: [debug] Trying to find a connected android device
> info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Users\Eagle\Desktop\Appium\Installations and Configuration\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe" devices
> info: [debug] 1 device(s) connected
> info: Found device 169.254.160.177:5555
> info: [debug] Setting device id to 169.254.160.177:5555
> info: [debug] Waiting for device to be ready and to respond to shell commands (timeout = 5)
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Users\Eagle\Desktop\Appium\Installations and Configuration\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s 169.254.160.177:5555 wait-for-device
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Users\Eagle\Desktop\Appium\Installations and Configuration\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s 169.254.160.177:5555 shell "echo 'ready'"
> info: [debug] Starting logcat capture
> info: [debug] Getting device API level
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Users\Eagle\Desktop\Appium\Installations and Configuration\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s 169.254.160.177:5555 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
> info: [debug] Device is at API Level 19
> info: Device API level is: 19
> info: [debug] Extracting strings for language: default
> info: [debug] Apk doesn't exist locally
> info: [debug] Could not get strings, but it looks like we had an old strings file anyway, so ignoring
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Users\Eagle\Desktop\Appium\Installations and Configuration\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s 169.254.160.177:5555 shell "rm -rf /data/local/tmp/strings.json"
> info: [debug] Not uninstalling app since server not started with --full-reset
> info: [debug] Skipping install since we launched with a package instead of an app path
> info: [debug] Forwarding system:4724 to device:4724
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Users\Eagle\Desktop\Appium\Installations and Configuration\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s 169.254.160.177:5555 forward tcp:4724 tcp:4724
> info: [debug] Pushing appium bootstrap to device...
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Users\Eagle\Desktop\Appium\Installations and Configuration\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s 169.254.160.177:5555 push "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Appium\\node_modules\\appium\\build\\android_bootstrap\\AppiumBootstrap.jar" /data/local/tmp/
> info: [debug] Pushing settings apk to device...
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Users\Eagle\Desktop\Appium\Installations and Configuration\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s 169.254.160.177:5555 install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\settings_apk\settings_apk-debug.apk"
> info: [debug] Pushing unlock helper app to device...
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Users\Eagle\Desktop\Appium\Installations and Configuration\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s 169.254.160.177:5555 install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\build\unlock_apk\unlock_apk-debug.apk"
> info: Starting App
> info: [debug] Attempting to kill all 'uiautomator' processes
> info: [debug] Getting all processes with 'uiautomator'
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Users\Eagle\Desktop\Appium\Installations and Configuration\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s 169.254.160.177:5555 shell "ps 'uiautomator'"
> info: [debug] No matching processes found
> info: [debug] Running bootstrap
> info: [debug] spawning: C:\Users\Eagle\Desktop\Appium\Installations and Configuration\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 169.254.160.177:5555 shell uiautomator runtest AppiumBootstrap.jar -c io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap -e pkg com.myapplicationdev -e disableAndroidWatchers false
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] WARNING: linker: libdvm.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap:
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=UiAutomatorTestRunner
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testRunServer
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 1
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Socket opened on port 4724
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Appium Socket Server Ready
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Loading json...
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Registered crash watchers.
> info: [debug] Waking up device if it's not alive
> info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["wake",{}]
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Client connected
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"wake","params":{}}
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: wake
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Users\Eagle\Desktop\Appium\Installations and Configuration\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s 169.254.160.177:5555 shell "dumpsys window"
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":true,"status":0}
> info: [debug] Screen already unlocked, continuing.
> info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["getDataDir",{}]
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"getDataDir","params":{}}
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
> info: [debug] dataDir set to: /data
> info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["compressedLayoutHierarchy",{"compressLayout":false}]
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: getDataDir
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":"\/data","status":0}
> info: [debug] Getting device API level
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Users\Eagle\Desktop\Appium\Installations and Configuration\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s 169.254.160.177:5555 shell "getprop ro.build.version.sdk"
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"compressedLayoutHierarchy","params":{"compressLayout":false}}
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: compressedLayoutHierarchy
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":false,"status":0}
> info: [debug] Device is at API Level 19
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Users\Eagle\Desktop\Appium\Installations and Configuration\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s 169.254.160.177:5555 shell "am start -S -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000 -n com.myapplicationdev/com.myapplicationdev.MainActivity"
> info: [debug] Waiting for pkg "com.myapplicationdev" and activity "com.myapplicationdev.MainActivity" to be focused
> info: [debug] Getting focused package and activity
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Users\Eagle\Desktop\Appium\Installations and Configuration\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s 169.254.160.177:5555 shell "dumpsys window windows"
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Users\Eagle\Desktop\Appium\Installations and Configuration\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s 169.254.160.177:5555 shell "getprop ro.build.version.release"
> info: [debug] Device is at release version 4.4.4
> info: [debug] Device launched! Ready for commands
> info: [debug] Setting command timeout to the default of 60 secs
> info: [debug] Appium session started with sessionId 60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 303 12203.233 ms - 74 
> info: --> GET /wd/hub/session/60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6 {}
> info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"platform":"LINUX","browserName":"Android","platformVersion":"4.4.4","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"appActivity":"com.myapplicationdev.MainActivity","appPackage":"com.myapplication","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"donatello"},"appActivity":"com.myapplicationdev.MainActivity","appPackage":"com.myapplication","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"169.254.160.177:5555"},"sessionId":"60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6"}
> info: <-- GET /wd/hub/session/60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6 200 7.357 ms - 644 {"status":0,"value":{"platform":"LINUX","browserName":"Android","platformVersion":"4.4.4","webStorageEnabled":false,"takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"databaseEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":false,"warnings":{},"desired":{"appActivity":"com.myapplicationdev.MainActivity","appPackage":"com.myapplication","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"donatello"},"appActivity":"com.myapplicationdev.MainActivity","appPackage":"com.myapplication","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"169.254.160.177:5555"},"sessionId":"60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6"}
> info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6/element {"using":"xpath","value":"//android.view.View[@content-desc='1']"}
> info: [debug] Waiting up to 0ms for condition
> info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["find",{"strategy":"xpath","selector":"//android.view.View[@content-desc='1']","context":"","multiple":false}]
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"xpath","selector":"//android.view.View[@content-desc='1']","context":"","multiple":false}}
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: find
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding //android.view.View[@content-desc='1'] using XPATH with the contextId:  multiple: false
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[CLASS=android.view.View, INSTANCE=4]
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":{"ELEMENT":"1"},"status":0}
> info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"1"},"sessionId":"60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6"}
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6/element 200 512.676 ms - 87 {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"1"},"sessionId":"60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6"}
> info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6/element/1/click {"id":"1"}
> info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["element:click",{"elementId":"1"}]
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:click","params":{"elementId":"1"}}
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: click
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":true,"status":0}
> info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":true,"sessionId":"60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6"}
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6/element/1/click 200 545.815 ms - 76 {"status":0,"value":true,"sessionId":"60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6"}
> info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6/element {"using":"xpath","value":"//android.view.View[@content-desc='1']"}
> info: [debug] Waiting up to 0ms for condition
> info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["find",{"strategy":"xpath","selector":"//android.view.View[@content-desc='1']","context":"","multiple":false}]
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"xpath","selector":"//android.view.View[@content-desc='1']","context":"","multiple":false}}
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: find
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding //android.view.View[@content-desc='1'] using XPATH with the contextId:  multiple: false
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[CLASS=android.view.View, INSTANCE=5]
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":{"ELEMENT":"2"},"status":0}
> info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"2"},"sessionId":"60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6"}
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6/element 200 312.892 ms - 87 {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"2"},"sessionId":"60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6"}
> info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6/element/2/click {"id":"2"}
> info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["element:click",{"elementId":"2"}]
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:click","params":{"elementId":"2"}}
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: click
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":true,"status":0}
> info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":true,"sessionId":"60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6"}
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6/element/2/click 200 635.001 ms - 76 {"status":0,"value":true,"sessionId":"60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6"}
> info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6/element {"using":"xpath","value":"//android.view.View[@content-desc='1']"}
> info: [debug] Waiting up to 0ms for condition
> info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["find",{"strategy":"xpath","selector":"//android.view.View[@content-desc='1']","context":"","multiple":false}]
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"xpath","selector":"//android.view.View[@content-desc='1']","context":"","multiple":false}}
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: find
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding //android.view.View[@content-desc='1'] using XPATH with the contextId:  multiple: false
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[CLASS=android.view.View, INSTANCE=5]
> info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"3"},"sessionId":"60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6"}
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6/element 200 693.547 ms - 87 {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"3"},"sessionId":"60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6"}
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":{"ELEMENT":"3"},"status":0}
> info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6/element/3/click {"id":"3"}
> info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["element:click",{"elementId":"3"}]
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:click","params":{"elementId":"3"}}
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: click
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":true,"status":0}
> info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":true,"sessionId":"60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6"}
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6/element/3/click 200 457.090 ms - 76 {"status":0,"value":true,"sessionId":"60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6"}
> info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6/element {"using":"xpath","value":"//android.view.View[@content-desc='1']"}
> info: [debug] Waiting up to 0ms for condition
> info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["find",{"strategy":"xpath","selector":"//android.view.View[@content-desc='1']","context":"","multiple":false}]
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"xpath","selector":"//android.view.View[@content-desc='1']","context":"","multiple":false}}
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: find
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding //android.view.View[@content-desc='1'] using XPATH with the contextId:  multiple: false
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[CLASS=android.view.View, INSTANCE=6]
> info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"4"},"sessionId":"60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6"}
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6/element 200 233.350 ms - 87 {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"4"},"sessionId":"60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6"}
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":{"ELEMENT":"4"},"status":0}
> info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6/element/4/click {"id":"4"}
> info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["element:click",{"elementId":"4"}]
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:click","params":{"elementId":"4"}}
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: click
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":true,"status":0}
> info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":true,"sessionId":"60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6"}
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6/element/4/click 200 437.992 ms - 76 {"status":0,"value":true,"sessionId":"60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6"}
> info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6/element {"using":"xpath","value":"//android.view.View[@content-desc='1']"}
> info: [debug] Waiting up to 0ms for condition
> info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["find",{"strategy":"xpath","selector":"//android.view.View[@content-desc='1']","context":"","multiple":false}]
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"xpath","selector":"//android.view.View[@content-desc='1']","context":"","multiple":false}}
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: find
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding //android.view.View[@content-desc='1'] using XPATH with the contextId:  multiple: false
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[CLASS=android.view.View, INSTANCE=7]
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":{"ELEMENT":"5"},"status":0}
> info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"5"},"sessionId":"60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6"}
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6/element 200 371.092 ms - 87 {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"5"},"sessionId":"60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6"}
> info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6/element/5/click {"id":"5"}
> info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["element:click",{"elementId":"5"}]
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:click","params":{"elementId":"5"}}
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: click
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":true,"status":0}
> info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":true,"sessionId":"60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6"}
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6/element/5/click 200 231.014 ms - 76 {"status":0,"value":true,"sessionId":"60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6"}
> info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6/element {"using":"xpath","value":"//android.view.View[@index='2']"}
> info: [debug] Waiting up to 0ms for condition
> info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["find",{"strategy":"xpath","selector":"//android.view.View[@index='2']","context":"","multiple":false}]
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"find","params":{"strategy":"xpath","selector":"//android.view.View[@index='2']","context":"","multiple":false}}
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: find
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding //android.view.View[@index='2'] using XPATH with the contextId:  multiple: false
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[CLASS=android.view.View, INSTANCE=3]
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":{"ELEMENT":"6"},"status":0}
> info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"6"},"sessionId":"60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6"}
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6/element 200 170.945 ms - 87 {"status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"6"},"sessionId":"60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6"}
> info: --> POST /wd/hub/session/60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6/element/6/click {"id":"6"}
> info: [debug] Pushing command to appium work queue: ["element:click",{"elementId":"6"}]
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"element:click","params":{"elementId":"6"}}
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type ACTION
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command action: click
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":true,"status":0}
> info: [debug] Responding to client with success: {"status":0,"value":true,"sessionId":"60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6"}
> info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session/60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6/element/6/click 200 326.695 ms - 76 {"status":0,"value":true,"sessionId":"60ee80cd-ab62-4dcd-8e18-aac9de15aed6"}
> info: [debug] Didn't get a new command in 60 secs, shutting down...
> info: Shutting down appium session
> info: [debug] Pressing the HOME button
> info: [debug] executing cmd: "C:\Users\Eagle\Desktop\Appium\Installations and Configuration\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe" -s 169.254.160.177:5555 shell "input keyevent 3"
> info: [debug] Stopping logcat capture
> info: [debug] Logcat terminated with code null, signal SIGTERM
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"shutdown"}
> info: [debug] Sent shutdown command, waiting for UiAutomator to stop...
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Got command of type SHUTDOWN
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":"OK, shutting down","status":0}
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Closed client connection
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=.
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=UiAutomatorTestRunner
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testRunServer
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 0
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] Test results for WatcherResultPrinter=.
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] Time: 87.663
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] OK (1 test)
> info: [debug] [UIAUTOMATOR STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1
> info: [debug] UiAutomator shut down normally
> info: [debug] Cleaning up android objects
> info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
> info: [debug] We shut down because no new commands came in
```

Comment: My best guess is that the XPath expression does match something else that gets clicked instead the login button.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I really don't think the problem is from the xpath. This is because when i move the login to the first line of the code it was clicked and i got a pop up requesting me to put the 5 digit pin first.

Comment: in order give proper solution for this we need following this,
1. Full Appium logs
2. UIautomator screenshot

Comment: please see appium logs below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to click on the coordinates of the element and see if it works?

Try something like this -

```
Point point = element.getLocation();
int x = point.x;
int y = point.y;

TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(driverMobile);
touchAction.tap(x, y).perform();
```

Comment: Thanks Anish, using TouchAction worked. I observered that when i printed the cordinate from point, i got  (179, 424), so the it didn't click on the button. but when i got my cordinates manually using ui automator, i was able to click on it.

Comment: Hi Ayoaudu, were it the same coordinates that you used in both the cases. Generally I try to add an offset of 5 or 10px to the coordinates, so that it works incase the original coordinates are the corners. So the code that I generally use is - `touchAction.tap(x+10, y+10).perform();`

Comment: Hello Anish, the cordinate i eventually used was different from what i got from point. Point gave me (179,424), but i used (504, 409) that i got from uiautomator. I'm actually concerned that the code will not work if i'm using another device that is bigger or smaller.

Comment: ,I just tried something now, i tried to get the element cordinate at the begining of my code execution using the code below.
    WebElement D =dr.findElementByXPath("//android.view.View[@index='2']");
    Point pt = D.getLocation();
    System.out.println(pt);
(824,452)
After execution some set of code, i got the cordinate again with the code below and i realized they are different. this is confusing.
WebElement E=dr.findElementByXPath("//android.view.View[@index='2']");
Point point = E.getLocation();
System.out.println(point); 
 (179, 424)
what could be responsible for this?

Comment: When you are executing some other code, then is there any changes happening in the screen (scrolling, some other elements getting displayed etc). One possible reason can be that during 2nd time, element at index=2 might be some other element. Can you check if the code refers to the same object both these times?

Comment: the screen is a static one, so there is no scrolling and also the screen does not change. It's only one element/ object that refers to that xpath. If you look at the appium log i attached, you will notice that the INSTANCE value keeps increasing for every command i.e. INSTANCE=1, INSTANCE=2 e.t.c. The elementid was also increasing e.g. "elementId":"6","elementId":"3" Is that the right behaviour?